# the distinction between inchoatives and unaccusatives

Tags: semantics, verbs, unaccusative

I'm having difficulty understanding what are inchoative verbs and how they are different from unaccusative verbs. Is it generally the case that inchoatives are subsumed under unaccusatives?

Verbs of motion, "roll" for example, show the causative/inchoative alternation. But I assume it is not an unaccusative verb. Then is it okay to say the intransitive use of the verb roll is inchoative, but its subject is not a patient, hence not an unaccusative verb?

**eg. The ball rolled down the hill.**

How about the verb 'fall'? It's an unaccusative verb. Is it an inchoative verb?

**eg. Susan fell.**

And 'suffocate' as in **'Many dogs have suffocated in hot cars.**' The subject is a patient. Is it an unaccusative verb? and inchoative as well?

Comment: You can't really consider the verbs out of context. Can you please [edit] this to give example sentences for each verb you want to discuss? Also, please be careful with your terminology - verbs aren't called 'accusatives' for example.

Comment: I made some mistakes. sorry. Is that okay now? I'm not a language student so I understand if my question doesn't make sense and it's hard to answer the question. (I'm not a native speaker either.)

Comment: That's much better thanks :) Now what makes you think that 'fell' is unaccusative? It's intransitive, so it can't be unaccusative.

Comment: Because the subject of 'fall' isn't an agentive, self-initiative subject? The subject can be answered to a question, "what happened to Susan?" instead of "what did Susan do?". And the underlying subject is maybe gravity or just some natural force that is not identified in the realization of the verb meaning(?) Therefore the sentence takes on sort of 'an event happens by itself' sense. I think I've seen it treated as an unaccusative verb. Is it not?

Comment: It is good to be focusing on the semantic roles like that, but *fell* is just an ordinary intransitive. Unaccusatives, like passives, are valence changes of transitive verbs. Intransitive verbs can take lots of different semantic roles in their subject.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input. Then, what's the category of kinds of verbs the verb 'fall' fall into? It's obviously not an unergative verb. The subject is not a typical agentive subject.

Comment: I'd just call it intransitive! Passive, unaccusative, unergative are types of valence changing constructions. *fall* is in its normal state. You could look up Beth Levin's verb classes, but that's a different kind of categorisation.

Comment: And can you comment on inchoatives? how they are different from unaccusatives?

Comment: The inchoative is related to aspect: it indicates that a process is beginning. I don't see how that would have anything to do with the semantic roles of the subject.

Comment: Looking at the causative/inchoative alternation I don't know why they call it an inchoative. causative/unaccusative would be a better name for the alternation. Or maybe they're using inchoative but without any sense of it being limited to the beginning of a process. Lots of labels get used very inconsistently!

Comment: "The term inchoative verb is used by generative grammarians to refer to a class of verbs that reflect a change of state; e. g., "John aged" or "The fog cleared". This usage bears little or no relationship to the aspectual usage described above." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchoative_aspect))

Comment: " 
Looking at the causative/inchoative alternation I don't know why they call it an inchoative. causative/unaccusative would be a better name for the alternation."  ----> Tell me about it!  Thanks for the information. It's really helpful.

Comment: I dig a little and found that David Purlmutter, to whom the birth of "unaccusative hypothesis" is attributed, in his 1978 paper, took 'fall' into the category of unaccusatives (p.162) But I can see a different point of view can result in a different analysis so you might have yet another category for 'fall', as you put it, "just intransitive", maybe? Anyway all these terms are helluva confusing and making me throw up already!

Answer (score 3):

*Unaccusativity* is a syntactic notion: a predicate has a single argument position.

*Inchoativity* is a semantic notion: a predicate denotes the beginning of an event.

Some verbs are inchoative and unaccusative (e.g., *the sauce thickened*), but this is a coincidence, not a significant fact.

Comment: can you please provide some references on which you based your claims?